# JavaScript > Why doesn't the Object "Class Name" show in my browser terminal?

Tags: javascript, class, firefox, console.log, firefox-developer-tools

So I am learning JavaScript. And in this training they are teaching about Object Class. And at a certain point, they show that in the browser console, the object class name is shown when console.log.

But, when I am doing it, it does not happen. It only shows that it is an Object, but it does not show the class name. Any idea what is wrong?

p.s. I am using the Mozilla Firefox browser.

[[image: This training shows "Backpack" as the object class name in the browser terminalThis one here is my code, and it does not show the object class name in my browser console]

Comment: It depends on the console you're using, and on the code. You'll want to ask your instructor.

Comment: "*when I am doing it*" - doing what? Please [edit] your question to include the code you executed.

Comment: Yes, Firefox doesn't seem to show the class,  your teacher was likely using webkit based browser like Chrome.  So if you want to see the class in Firefox you will need to expand the prototype and you should see something like -> `constructor: class Backpack`

Comment: @keith your feedback helped. The instructor is indeed using Chrome, and I am using Firefox. I will be trying this on the Chrome browser to see if the output is the same as the instructor's. Thanks a ton... Cheers!